# Adjusting x-axis labels and preventing them from being cutoff in Pandas / matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to get a label on each x-axis point. With the current code, the labels are chopped off on the longer x-axis titles, and only every so many x axis points gets a label.

How do I make the image canvas bigger to not cutoff the x-axis labels?

How do I force each point to be labeled on the x-axis?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

def plotcsv(csvpath):
    pdata = pd.read_csv(csvpath)
    pdata = pdata.set_index('Build') #Adds build column for names of x axis points

    try: # sometimes there's an extra column if there were extra commas in the csv
        pdata = pdata.drop(pdata.columns[4], axis = 1)
    except:
        pass

    p = pdata.plot(title="Power vs Build", rot=-10)
    p.set_ylabel("W")
    # print(pdata.index)
    # print(pdata['Build'])
    # plt.xticks(pdata.index, rotation=90) # Doesn't work
    plt.savefig(csvpath + '.png')
```

Comment: It's hard to follow your question without seeing the data you're working with.  Are you talking about `pdata.plot(figsize=(20,10))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `plt.tight_layout()` before saving the plot.

Here's [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) on this topic.

Comment: It took me a few tries to discover that "before saving the plot" means that the call to df.plot.bar() must come before the call to plt.tight_layout().